Firebase User Creation with external SMS provider
Is there a way in firebase to create a user with just phone number only? Not using firebase phone auth or createUserWithEmailAndPassword since i would like to only user mobile number to verify otp during signup and create a new user.
I am working on a signup flow in mobile app where the user will just input their mobile number, verify OTP (twilio or any other SMS provider other than firebase phone auth as this is a little pricey for me) and then to create the user in firebase with that verified phone number only.

Did you find anything ?
